# How to install geth on RPi 3B?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, installation, raspberry-pi

- Raspberry Pi 3B (arm7) with Raspbian (which /etc/debian_version shows as 9.1)
- I'm logged in as the user `pi`.
- I'm following instructions from http://raspnode.com/diyEthereumGeth.html.

After installing go under `$HOME/bin/go`, I'm doing these commands:

```
cd go-ethereum
my path now includes /home/pi/bin/go/bin
make geth
```

I also tried `sudo make geth` and got the same error. **Oddly enough, sudo didn't ask me for my password** like on other linux machines I work on. At the make command I get these errors:

```
pi@rpi3b-cr:~/bin/go-ethereum $ make geth
build/env.sh go run build/ci.go install ./cmd/geth
internal/build/azure.go:23:2: cannot find package "github.com/Azure/azure-storage-go" in any of:
/home/pi/bin/go/src/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-go (from $GOROOT)
/home/pi/bin/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-go (from $GOPATH)
internal/build/pgp.go:27:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp" in any of:
/home/pi/bin/go/src/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp (from $GOROOT)
/home/pi/bin/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp (from $GOPATH)
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'geth' failed
make: *** [geth] Error 1
```

I also tried:

- `sudo apt-get install eth` and `sudo apt-get install ethereum` and neither could be found in the package repo.
  The error was "unable to locate package geth" or similar.

How do I install geth? Or even Parity? I have not been able to find instructions that work yet.

Thank you! I'm a noob when it comes  to installing a node, and to Rpi, although I know a little linux.

Comment: Hi there. Noting those instructions are nearly 2 years old, you might have more luck with a newer set: http://pinode.co.uk/ or https://pgaleone.eu/raspberry/ethereum/archlinux/2017/09/06/ethereum-node-raspberri-pi-3/. (Unsure what your issue actually is - others might know more.)

Comment: Thanks. @RichardHorrocks. I ordered a UPS and powered USB hub just for my RPi. My 1TB seagate USB drive seems to be drawing too much power and my video blinks off an on every few minutes, which I assume is a low power problem. (Video monitor is a VGA adapter but goes through an adapter to make it HDMI to connect it to the RPi.)

Answer (score 3):

I was in the exact same situation and solved this by installing the geth binary directly.

1. Find the latest arm7 geth binary [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/)
2. The link address is harder to track down, but it's `https://gethstore.blob.core.windows.net/builds/geth-linux-amd64-1.7.3-4bb3c89d.tar.gz`
3. `$ wget https://gethstore.blob.core.windows.net/builds/geth-linux-amd64-1.7.3-4bb3c89d.tar.gz`
4. untar it with `$ tar -xvf geth-linux-amd64-1.7.3-4bb3c89d.tar.gz`
5. then `cd geth-linux-amd64-1.7.3-4bb3c89d`
6. move the binary into your `/bin` with `sudo mv geth /usr/local/bin/`
7. Then make sure you've got it working with `$ geth license` or `$ geth h`

Credit to https://owocki.com/install-ethereum-geth-raspberry-pi-b/

Comment: Excellent instructions for me as a noob! Merry New Year!

Comment: Worked for me too.
Quick note, the link above is for amd64. For the Pi3, use arm7, such as the one below.
https://gethstore.blob.core.windows.net/builds/geth-linux-arm7-1.8.14-316fc7ec.tar.gz